# Is there a way to get the coordinates of a Segment that I draw on the HighCharts stockChart?

Tags: highcharts, stock

This is the chart I'm currently using: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/stock-tools-gui

I wanted to know if its possible to get the coordinates of the line segment (in code) drawn using their inbuilt line tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shapes added by using stock tools are stored as annotations and you can refer to them by:

```
chart.annotations[x].points;
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yf2c8oqk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations